# Where i must keep different types of files in asp.net mvc site in DB or in site root?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I am going to beg you for answering on my question. First of all, i develop a site which must provide uploading files and further downloading from this site. Where i must keep this files. P.s files can be defferent types such as .rar,.dov,.pdf etc. I must keep in data base adress of them or not. If you can exemplify please.
 I develop my site on Asp.Net MVC C#

Comment: There are pros and cons either way.  It's really up to you.  In general, the advice I tend to follow is that file systems are very well designed for storing files, relational databases not always quite so much.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed answer about pros and cons of storing files in the database vs flie system: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150787

An instruction of how to implement both approaches: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement username/password security for accessing the file data, then storing in SQL can help.  If that's not your goal, then using the filesystem will yield better performance.

I don't advise storing these files within your website itself, but in another location preferably on the same server.  You can use web.config  to store this location which makes it easy to configure between environments.